# How to replace values in a string using sed but keep the string intact

Tags: sed, string, variable

How to replace values in a string using sed but keep the string intact?

For example `echo "01XX1234"`

I'm looking to replace `XX` with a hex value and leave the `01` and the `1234` intact. I've tried every combination I can think of but `sed` is getting the better of me.

I can do it like this but is there an easier way?

```
echo "01XX1234" | sed -n 's/\(01..1234\)/01AB1234/g'
```

Comment: What hex value do you want to use?

Comment: Is this what you need? `echo "01XX1234" | sed 's/XX/AB/'`

Comment: for the example it doesn't matter, im writing a script thst takes a hed value for a specific object in a text file, rather than reference that file manually the manually editing another file accordingly in simply trying to understand sed so i can build a script for my purpose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sed` will only replace the matching substring of a string.

```
$ echo '01XX1234' | sed 's/XX/AF/'
01AF1234
```

If you intent to always replace the third and forth character but keep the first and second intact you can use:

```
$ echo '01XX1234' | sed 's/\(.\{2\}\).\{2\}/\1AF/'
01AF1234
```

- `\{2\}` means two occurrences of the character standing before (in this case `.`: any character)
- `\(...\)` parentheses are used to create a matching group; you can refer to the matched substring later in the pattern or in the replacement string
- `\1` refers to the first matched substring (in this case i.e. "01")

Comment: I think you meant "01" in the `\1` explanation.

Answer (score 3):

`echo "01XX1234" | sed 's/XX/AB/'`

or
`echo "01XX1234" | sed 's/\(01\).*\(1234\)/\1AB\2/'`

Comment: ill try this out, thanks for the quick replies

Answer (score 2):

Use the hold space:

```
> echo "01XX1234" | sed -n 'h;s/01..1234/01AB1234/g;p;x;p'
01AB1234
01XX1234
```

sed commands:

- h --> move pattern space to hold space
- p --> print
- x --> swap hold space and pattern space